# Return back to the TabBar main screen

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I have an app with tabs at the bottom. On the more tab I have two thing in the list called settings and legal. When I click on settings or legal I open up the settings or legal view. When I click on the home tab bar and then return back to the more tab it returns back to where I was before I left. Is there anyway possible to go back to the main view of the more tab?

[image: My Issue]
EDIT

I have my navigation inside of my tab bar controller(like second image).
[image]

Comment: write in viewDidUnload of legal screen and setting screen ..
[self.tabBarController popToRootViewController];
try this one

Comment: TabBarControllers don't have a root view controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using a `UITabBarController`? If so, you can set the delegate of it when you create it or in your nib, and listen for selections:

```
-(void) tabBarController:(UITabBarController*)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController*)viewController {

    // Check if the selected tab is a UINavigationController
    if ([viewController isKindOfClass:[UINavigationController class]]) {

        UINavigationController* nav = (UINavigationController*) viewController;
        [nav popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];

    }

}
```

Comment: It should go onto the view controller that is presenting the tabs, or the app delegate if it's the root view...

Comment: that code does not work in app delegate. It is the root view but that code still doesn't solve my issue

Comment: Did you set your app delegate class as the tab controller's delegate?

Comment: No I did not. That was the issue. I hate when its something little like that. Thank you so much!! @jjv360